# Origin null is not allowed from Control-Allowed-Origin when use jquery header link button

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to only change page with jquery mobile/cordova on android phone.
My simple codes:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Event List</h1>
        <a href="options.html" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
</div>
```

If I click options button,"Error loading page" looks for few seconds.Logcat:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/Users/btstajer/Desktop/workspace/Fetcher/assets/www/options.html.
>   Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Hey I found problem.Due to the jquery version differences.
Such as:
If jquery-2.1.1.min.js the above does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

does not work.
But If jquery-2.1.1.min.js bottom,work but such is not seen its css file.

```
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

What's the matter?? If I use jquery-1.8.3.min.js work fine but I need this version.help me
And I tried on Chrome and Firefox.Chrome gave the same error.But firefox worked succesfully.Any ideas? thanks..

Comment: Have you set `<access origin="*"/>` in config.xml?

Comment: Yes of course,I get same error despite this.different ideas?

Comment: I don't find any solution to this problem.Maybe due to the version differences(jquerymobile,cordova) ?

Comment: No specific answer, but there's lots of tricks and tips on this page, check it out: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Comment: how you are calling your index.html page? directly by double click or by using tomcat?