# How to hidden to ajax loader icon?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

This icon is center of screen every open.In web browser,this icon is turning.But In phone,this icon is not turning.just standing until click a button.When click the button,hidden.How can I hide alltime this icon?
screen
[image: icon]

It'S my init:

```
$('#olayListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
 $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.disabled = true;
getOlayList();
```

});
I tried first answer.But doesnt work.jqery-2.1.1.min.js jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js

> my fiddle-->[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DGb8G/)

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? What you provided is not enough for people help you troubleshoot because there is a variety of possibilities

Comment: I changed my post.If you want the see all codes,I change again.thanks

Comment: It will help too if you also provide your html. A jsfiddle may even be better.

Comment: Seems like you've switched the blocks for JS and HTML in that fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$.mobile.loading('hide')
```

after you are done loading a page

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable the loader at initialization:

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.disabled = true;
});
```

API doc: http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/

EDIT:

For that version of JQM, try these two lines:

```
$.mobile.loadPage.defaults.showLoadMsg = false;
$.mobile.changePage.defaults.showLoadMsg = false;
```

Comment: doesnt work I changed my post If you want,look.I tried your answer.thanks

Comment: Would you look at these question?-I have problems with jquery 's versions.-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758847/origin-null-is-not-allowed-from-control-allowed-origin-when-use-jquery-header-li

Comment: `$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){ $.mobile.changePage.defaults.showLoadMsg = false; });` is what worked for me